# Nested IF statement only working when outside IF changes

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm trying my hand at VBA.

I have a statement that says:

```
Sub PM()

Set rn = ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Cells(1, 1)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C27")) Is Nothing Then
If Range("C27") = 3 Then
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Option Button 28").Select
Selection.Enabled = False
If Range("J57") < 455 Then
Range("J56") = False
Else
Range("J56") = True
End If
Else
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Option Button 28").Select
Selection.Enabled = True
End If
rn.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

When I change cell C27, the value passed to cell J56 works perfectly. But once the value in C27 is chosen, and I then change cell J57, J56 doesn't change accordingly as it should. I have to change C27 value again to trigger J56 to reflect the right value.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where are the end ifs?. Are you reliant on C27 being a 3 in order to evaluate J57

Comment: @dave: endifs are not required in the case of a single statement followin the condition

Comment: @yorik I am aware of that but OP stated nested ifs meaning there has to be "end if",  or else they are not nested are they!

Comment: So I have added the rest, but I think I see that I only have 1 End If. This is probably my issue?

Comment: What is this? `worksheet_change`? And your second if only fires if the first if is true

Comment: Yes I think that's my issues. I'm going to post the whole of my code incase that makes it clearer.

Comment: Can you tell us where Sub PM() is called from: what triggers its execution? Also, you set up "option button 28" selection and "enabled" to true whether c27 is 3 or else not 3, you can move that outside the conditional branching

Comment: Sorry one of the "option button 28" was supposed to be False. I've edited it. Sorry I'm not sure what triggers the Sub PM(). It's in Module 2 if that helps!?

Comment: Not at all. Find out.

Comment: Well when I edit the macro, the window only shows everything that I have posted. I don't know where to look for what triggers it's execution.

Comment: add the word `stop` on the line immediately before `end sub`. This will pause execution. Hit F8 once, this will step through execution by one line. This should put you immediately after the call to `sub PM()`, if it does not try hitting f8 one more time. Hit f5 to run without stepping.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing wildly here, but I expect that you are calling this code from an Event fired on c27 only, so if you edit j57, the function/sub is not called.